# Connection failed to broker: mqtt://localhost:1883

Tags: mqtt, raspberry-pi3, node-red

I'm facing issues on the connectivity between raspberry pi 3 with the Node-red MQTT.

My Raspberry Pi 3 shown as below:

> Starting as a systemd service. 8 Sep 03:27:30 - [info]
>
> [mqtt-broker:165e8c2d.4cb0d4] Connection failed to broker:
>
> mqtt://localhost:1883 8 Sep 03:27:45 - [info]
>
> [mqtt-broker:165e8c2d.4cb0d4] Connection failed to broker:
>
> mqtt://localhost:1883

Can anyone help me with this error please? Thanks..

Comment: Node-RED does not include an MQTT broker. Have you installed and started your own broker in the Pi?

Comment: You mean installed the MQTT broker on my Pi? I did not install it. Can you please help me what should I do to solve this error ?

Comment: If you want to use an MQTT broker you need to install one. Mosquitto is the most common choice of MQTT broker for a Pi. http://www.instructables.com/id/Installing-MQTT-BrokerMosquitto-on-Raspberry-Pi/

Answer (score 2):

Node-RED does not include an MQTT broker; you need to install one yourself.

[Mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/) is probably the most popular broker for running locally. There are instructions for installing it on a variety of operating systems on their [downloads page](https://mosquitto.org/download/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Appreaciate